# Spark java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, cloudera

I am trying to read parquet file and perform some operations on it and save the result as parquet on HDFS. I am doing it using Spark. While doing so I am getting following exception.

```
java.io.EOFException: Premature EOF: no length prefix available
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.PBHelper.vintPrefixed(PBHelper.java:2203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.datatransfer.PipelineAck.readFields(PipelineAck.java:176)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer$ResponseProcessor.run(DFSOutputStream.java:867)
```

Any help as to what can be the cause and solution for the same.

Using CDH 5.4.1

Comment: show us what u have tried so far...

Comment: Try using coalesce to decrease number of partitions while writing. If it doesn't work maybe you could post your code to help debug.

Comment: Not enough background info or troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Voted to close, but also posted a generic answer, which is probably as good as it gets with the given info.

Answer (score 0):

Premature EOF stands for Premature End Of File.

No code was posted, so I cannot provide a more specific solution, but there are two ways this error can occur:

1. If you are using a library that is still new/somewhat untested, you might find there is a problem with it in some corner cases
2. More likely however, is that you made a mistake in your code. This could be as simple as a syntax error, but could also be more subtle such as calling something in the wrong way.